# Populating a column based on value of another column (SQL)

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I'm using SQLite and have a table with 3 columns. The first column is populated with data and the other 2 columns currently contain null values.

I want to take the text in the first column, split it up, and populate columns 2 and 3 with this text.

E.g. in our first row, column1 contains the text 'NORTH/SOUTH'. Now I want to put the word 'NORTH' in column2 and the word 'SOUTH' in column3. I want to do this for all rows in the table, splitting up the text in column1 and using it to populate columns 2 and 3.

Can I do this merely using SQLite and SQL commands? Or do I need to use other software or programming languages? Advice on the actual code required would be awesome too.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you find it useful, it is appreciated an up vote & consider accepting it as answered. See here [What should I do when someone answers my question?] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: done. my first thread here so learning how it works. my upvote doesnt show publicly because i have less than 15 rep

Comment: Fine. Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your given data,
Try with this query:

```
UPDATE table
SET column_2 = substr(col1,1,INSTR(col1,'/')),
    column_3 = substr(col1,INSTR(col1,'/'),length(col1));
```